# Tkinter label act like an entry()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The entry() widget that tkinter has incorporated doesn't satisfy all my needs. So can I program a label to act like an entry()? Is there another possible way of making my own custom entry widget?

Comment: What are "all your needs"?

Comment: Width, height and image setting as bg.

Comment: width and height are easily solvable. It is only the background that is difficult. You might want to reconsider just how badly you need to use an image as a background. There's a reason why the vast majority of input boxes in GUIs around the world have a solid background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't program a label to act as an entry. Your best choice would be to start with a canvas. It as a text item that is editable, though it lacks many of the built-in features of an entry widget. I think all of the fundamental features are there.

A good place to start would be http://effbot.org/zone/editing-canvas-text-items.htm

Comment: Where can I find some reference on how to build your own custom entry() widget for Tkinter?